# Wordpress - is_single() -> Load scripts of plugin, in footer

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to load the scripts of [**kk Star Rating plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/), in footer and, only in single.

I edited the plugin, and the load in footer is ok, but this show in every page.

I want to load only in single post.

This is the **original code**:

```
add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'js'));
add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css'));
add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css_custom'));
add_action('admin_init', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'admin_scripts'));
```

I try this:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'js'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css_custom'));
    add_action('admin_init', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'admin_scripts'));
  }
```

and this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','copy_script');

function copy_script() {
   if ( is_single() ) {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'js'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css_custom'));
    add_action('admin_init', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'admin_scripts'));
  }
}
```

but anything does work, how can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is_singular('post')`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'copy_script');

function copy_script() {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'js'));
        add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css'));
        add_action('wp_footer', array($kkStarRatings_obj, 'css_custom'));
    }
}
```

I removed the admin scripts because I don't think you need them in a single post.

PS: you should enqueue the scripts using [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: I try, but does work :/ i change the `add_action` with `wp_enqueue_scripts` but this nothing happended.